# ElementTree.ParseError: reference to invalid character number

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I get

> ElementTree.ParseError: reference to invalid character number

when parsing XML that contains the following as a tag value: `loca&#1;t`

My code looks like:

```
respXML = httpResponse.content
#also possible respXML = httpResponse.content.decode("utf-8") 
#but both get the same error

#this line throws the error
respRoot = ET.fromstring(respXML)
```

How can I bulletproof my parser against seemingly invalid character numbers?

Comment: `&#1;` represents the control character START OF HEADING. If an XML parser encounters that character, it should throw an error. The character is forbidden in XML 1.0 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets).

Answer (score 1):

That looks like html. See if using the html package on the input string before anything else. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html

```
>>> import html
>>> test = "loca&#1;t"
>>> html.unescape(test)
'local'
```

Then convert some known unicode characters to their equivalents. i.e

```
“ => "
’ => '
...
```

Finally replace double spaces to single space.

Since it'll be pretty cumbersome to address everything successfully upfront - I recommend placing specific exceptions and writing the bad line to file. 
One by one address each error in the output file by adding more rules.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes find useful to save the original input characters with an regex pattern, such as `(re.sub(r'&#([a-zA-Z0-9]+);?', r'[#\1;]', s)`. For example, with

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import re
s = "<Tag>loca&#1;t</Tag>"
```

using html.unescape produces

```py
ET.fromstring(html.unescape(s)).text
#Out: 'locat'
```

but the regex pattern mentioned produces

```py
ET.fromstring(re.sub(r'&#([a-zA-Z0-9]+);?', r'[#\1;]', s)).text
#Out: 'loca[#1;]t'
```

which preserves the "bad characters".